# GTA Online, What happens if I DONT transfer my avatar?

Tags: ps3, ps4, grand-theft-auto-online

I have GTA online on PS3. My avatar has a nice place and some decent cars. I just got a PS4 and GTA Online for it.

I have a friend who has GTA:O on his PS3. I learned I can't play with him on the PS4 if I transfer.

Can I simply have 2 online avatars attached to the same PSN account? Can I still play on the PS3 with my buddy if I play on the PS4?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can transfer your data to PS4 and still play on PS3. But if you level up, buy cars or do anything after the transfer on either console. Only the console you did that on will be affected.

However not transferring your avatar. Well it has no effect. You basically start a new game